# A proof for condition under which a monoid must also be a group: is it correct?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, monoid

Let $(M, \cdot)$ be a monoid, where $|M| = k$, for some $k > 1, k \in \mathbb{N}$. The elements of this monoid have a special property: for any $a, b, x \in M$:

$$ a \cdot x = b \cdot x \Rightarrow a = b$$

Pick an element $a \in M$ such that $a \neq 1$. Define $a^0 = 1$ (is this okay to do?), and $a^n = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} a $ ($\prod_{i = 1}^{i = 2} x = x \cdot x$). Write out the following sequence:

$$ a^1, a^2, \dots, a^{k + 1}$$

By the pigeonhole principle, there must exist some $i, j \in \{1, 2, \dots, k + 1\}$ such that $a^i = a^j$ where without WLOG $i < j$. Thus we have:

\begin{align}
&\quad\;\; a^i = a^j &&\text{hint: i < j, i > 0}\\
&\Leftrightarrow a^{i - 1} a = a^{j - 1} a &&\text{hint: special property of this monoid} \\
&\Rightarrow a^{i - 1} = a^{j - 1}
\end{align}

If $i - 1 = 0$ (i.e. $i = 1$) then we have shown that there exists some $j \in \{1,...,k+1\}$ such that $a^j = 1$. If $i - 1 > 0$ (i.e. $i > 0$) then we can repeat the procedure:

\begin{align}
&\quad\;\; a^{i - 1} = a^{j - 1} &&\text{hint: i - 1 < j - 1, i - 1 > 0}\\
&\Leftrightarrow a^{i - 2} a = a^{j - 2} a &&\text{hint: special property of this monoid} \\
&\Rightarrow a^{i - 2} = a^{j - 2}
\end{align}

And we can continue to do so until we finally hit some $r \in \{1,\dots,k\}$ such that $i - r = 0$ (recall that since $i < j$, $i \in \{1,\dots,k\}$) --- since $i \leq k$, we know we can do this in less than or equal to $k$ iterations.

Thus, we have shown that any sequence generated by the powers of such a monoid must contain $1$, or put another way, for any $a \in M$, there exists $i \in {1,\cdots,k}$ such that $a^i = 1$.

This implies that $a$ has a left inverse, because:

\begin{align}
&\quad\;\; a^i = 1 \\
&\Leftrightarrow a^{i - 1} \cdot a = 1 \\
&\Leftrightarrow a^{i - 1} = a^{-1}
\end{align}

We can do something similar to show that (due to the associativity of $\cdot$) $a$ also has a right inverse (which also happens to be $a^{i-1}$), or we can use the fact that if $a$ has a right inverse, then its right inverse is also a left inverse (proof omitted from this discussion).

Anyway, so every $a \in M$ also has an inverse, and thus, $(M, \cdot)$ is a group.

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It looks good to me. Rather than thinking about the powers $a^i$, you could prove the existence of inverses by observing that the given condition says that the mapping $x \mapsto xa$ is a 1-1 mapping from $M$ to itself, and, hence, as $M$ is finite, $x \mapsto xa$ is an onto mapping, so there is a $y$ with $xy = 1$.

Comment: Yes, but you should learn to write proofs more concisely. (Also the word "hint" is used in exercises, not in proofs.)